# Call Sub Statement from other pages

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to call Sub Statement from another pages (XAML) in windows phone 8.1 / windows 8.1. When I want to use code such as: 
Call NamePage.SubStatement() 
Its don't work. 
How can I do it? 
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? What does "don't work" mean exactly? What do you want to achieve? Why would you want to call a method of a non-instanciated or invisible page? Shouldn't SubStatement be part of the ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but if you make a function static in c# or shared in VB you can access it by the ClassName.functionName

Comment: if use static or shared function, I can't use something special such as I can't use navigation or other special thing. How can I do that?